# how can I check the asp.net form in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how can I check the inputs in my form in javascript?
I mean, for example, if the user doesnt enter anything in the input text, the asp.net action will not action and list with all the errors will display.

can anyone help?

Comment: Is there a specific task or scenario with validating inputs that you're trying to achieve? If so, would you be able to share some more details about it? If you're seeking general or initial guidance, Microsoft has fairly good tutorials in their documentation for sites built for either [.NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model) or [.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: Hey, I try to explain again. I built register form with 3 inpute: username, password and gender. I want to check with javascript if the inputs are valid. So first of all I want to check if the user have entered to the input "username" text, so I try to do:  var username = document.registrationForm.user_name.value; but than the action is acting. what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Lookat `Validation Tools` like the `RequiredFieldValidator`, the `RegularExpressionValidator` and the `ValidationSummary`. They run on the client with JavaScript. You can also validate on the server after.

(Visual Studio Toolbox.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var validate = $("form").validate()
var errors = validate.errorList;
```

It will hold array of errors.